# Set EnableRepeatGroupHeader option in subreport

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports

I am exporting my report in 3 versions, PDF, HTML and Excel. I have a main report and inside a subreport in which I have set the option EnableRepeatGroupHeader in design (I grouped because I need to show the header on every page of the PDF file). PDF works fine, but for the Excel and HTML exported files, I am getting the group header in the middle of the reports in one page. I found this code and tried to implement it, but got error: Not supported with subreports.

Here is the code, I have only one group here:

```
ReportDocument mainSubreport = mainReport.Subreports[pDetail.RptFileName];
GroupAreaFormat gf = (mainSubreport.ReportClientDocument.ReportDefController.ReportDefinition.GroupHeaderArea[0].Format as GroupAreaFormat);
gf.EnableRepeatGroupHeader = true;
```

Comment: You may not be able to do this, there are a number of commands from the Crystal API that you would normally be able to call on a ReportDocument that either just don't work or bomb out with exceptions just because they're called against a subreport.

Comment: Yes, true. I made a test report and tried to do the same thing in the main (not subreport), but again got the error. So, I made two copies of the same file, one with set EnableRepeatGroupHeader to true, and the other to false, in designer off course. The first one I am using for the PDF and the second for Excel and HTML. Thanks for your reply.